# MonoTouch - No Option to deploy application to iPad device?

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad, deployment, xamarin.ios

I have an application which I need to test on an iPad device, however there doesn't appear to be an option to do this.  I did initially create my application as iPhone only, but I've added an iPad storyboard, and I've adjusted the settings in the info.plist file in order to recognise this, however I still don't have the option to deploy to the iPad device.  I can deploy to the simulator but I really need to deploy to the device at this stage.  Please tell me I don't have to re-create the solution from scratch and declare it as universal from the start?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that deploying to the iPhone works as if you have deployed to the iPad.

Comment: Yes so it is. Just connect your iPad to your MAC and select Debug iPhone or Release iPhone. MonoDevelop detects that you have plugged in a iPad and it deploys your App to the iPad

Comment: MonoDevelop always says "iPhone" (it dates back from when there were only iPhones ;-) when it really means "iOS device" (which covers the iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad)